# Bundle JavaFX app with openjdk 11 + runtime

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-11

I've created a small HelloWorld Java app that relies on OpenJDK 11 and JavaFX. The app is packaged in a jar file which can only be run if I have installed Java 11 and JavaFX on my system separately.

Now I'd like to convert my jar into a [self-contained Java application](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/deploy/self-contained-application-packaging.htm#JSDPG583) which includes JavaFX and a fully-functional Java runtime environment. This will allow me to run my app without installing OpenJDK 11 (which presents technical hurdles such as setting PATH correctly etc).

I can find information about creating self-contained Java applications on Java 10 but I cannot find information about bundling a Java app with OpenJDK 11 and JavaFX.

How can I ship a self-contained Java app (which includes a java runtime) with OpenJDK 11 and JavaFX?

Comment: Check out http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Use jlink to make custom image. But must use only modular java app

Comment: Struggling with this as well.  I would expect the JavaFX runtime to have accommodated for this in a cross-platform way (e.g. `.jar!/../lib`)since it would be common for application developers relying on the technology.

Comment: Ok, figured it out.  Posting answer now.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## Modular Java, *jlink*, & *jpackage*

Follow [these tutorials](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/) found at the [new home for JavaFX](https://openjfx.io) after having [been spun out](https://gluonhq.com/gluon-and-javafx/) of Oracle to [Gluon](https://gluonhq.com).

You will need to write code using modular Java. Add JavaFX 11 as a dependency to your project. And use the new linking/packaging tools to bundle a subset of the JDK within your app.

Learn about:

- [*Java Platform Module System*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform_Module_System)
- *jlink* ([JEP 282](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/282))
- *jpackage* ([JEP 343](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/343))

## No more JRE

Oracle no longer intends for end-users to be installing a JRE or a JDK. [Java Applets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_applet) in a browser and [Java Web Start](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Web_Start) app delivery are both being phased out, leaving the end-user with no need for a JRE. Java-based apps are expected to bundle their own Java implementation. The only folks consciously installing a JDK will be developers & server-side sysadmins.

Important:

- Understand clearly the nature of the [*OpenJDK*](http://openjdk.java.net) project, as [explained in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenJDK).
- Know that Oracle has committed to feature-parity between its own branded *Oracle JDK* and the *OpenJDK* project. This commitment includes donations of previously-commercial features such as [*Flight Recorder*](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/328) and [*Mission Control*](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/jmc/).
- [*OpenJFX*](https://openjfx.io/), the open-source development of JavaFX, is [a part of the OpenJDK](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/openjfx/) project. OpenJFX may or may not be included in a build of OpenJDK. The [Java specifications](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/) do not require JavaFX functionality.
- At least two vendors provide an edition of their JDK product that comes bundled with the OpenJFX libraries:

  - *ZuluFX* from Azul Systems
  - *LibericaFX* from BellSoft
- Read this white paper by Oracle of 2018-03, [*Java Client Roadmap Update*](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/javaclientroadmapupdate2018mar-4414431.pdf)
- Read the white paper [*Java Is Still Free*](https://medium.com/@javachampions/java-is-still-free-2-0-0-6b9aa8d6d244), authored by key members of the Java community.

Here is a flowchart diagram that may help you finding and deciding amongst the various vendors providing a Java 11 implementation.

[image: Flowchart guiding you in choosing a vendor for a Java 11 implementation]

---

[image: Motivations in choosing a vendor for Java]

Comment: I think the "Java Is Still Free" whitepaper can be found at https://medium.com/@javachampions/java-is-still-free-2-0-0-6b9aa8d6d244.

Comment: @MihaiB Thanks, I updated the Answer to se the link you provided. FYI, Stack Overflow invites you to make such edits yourself if you are so inclined.

Answer (score 2):

You can bundle a whole JDK with your app and create a batch script to run your app using the bundled JDK. I know this approach will bloat up your release significantly, but the alternative is to ask your user to install JDK themselves, which is not trivial for non-tech savvy people. Or you can release both versions, one with JDK bundled and one without.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you just wait a little bit until the first EA release of the new jpackager tool is available. See http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/core-libs-dev/2018-October/056186.html

Answer (score 1):

**Native Libraries**

A challenge I encountered was to inform JavaFX about it's own native libraries (`.dll`, `.dylib`, `.so`, etc). Fortunately, getting the dylibs loaded is as simple as setting the `java.library.path` using `System.setProperty(...)`.

Historically, setting this variable is argued/perceived as pointless in Java as it's too late for the classloader (inferior to `-Djava.library.path`) and forcing it using reflection is a [forbidden security violation since Java 10](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24988095/3196753)... fortunately, JavaFX [actually honors this variable naturally](https://github.com/javafxports/openjdk-jfx/blob/d994bb861829e76124be07f465b4e298a772bf39/modules/javafx.graphics/src/main/java/com/sun/glass/utils/NativeLibLoader.java#L130) without any violations or hacks and will pick it up after it's set.

```
// Detect the path to the currently running jar
String jarPath = new File(this.getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath()).getCanonicalPath();

// Fix characters that get URL encoded when calling getPath()
jarPath = URLDecoder.decode(jarPath, "UTF-8");

String parentFolder = new File(jarPath).getParent();

// If libglass.dylib is next to the jar in a folder called "/bin"
System.setProperty("java.library.path",  parentFolder + "/bin");

// ... then make any javafx calls
```

**Java Libraries**

Naturally, the `.jar` files need to be accessible too.  I do this the same as I would any java bundle by [zipping them into the distribution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1821912/3196753) (making a single, large `.jar` file)

These `.jar` files should be consistent with all JavaFX 11 distributions and should be bundled accordingly.

```
javafx-swt.jar
javafx.base.jar
javafx.controls.jar
javafx.fxml.jar
javafx.graphics.jar
javafx.media.jar
javafx.swing.jar
javafx.web.jar
```

**Java 8 Compatibility**

Initial tests against Java 8 using the above technique are positive.  For now, I'm using Java version detection (not included in the above example) and ONLY setting `java.library.path` for Java 11 or higher.  Java 8 is EOL for personal use Dec 2019 (EOL for commercial use Jan 2019) so it is important to offer compatibility as clients migrate from one LTS release to another.

Answer (score 1):

(Using jdk14)

Starting by the fact that in order to use `jlink` **your main jar should be a module.**

**How?** Consider that you have a `maven` project. You just need to include `module-info.java` inside `src/main/java` dir and make sure that you `require` the modules that your app needs and you `export` the package that contains your main class. In most cases you will get a compile-time error when missing a `requires`. Have in mind that non-modular dependencies become [automatic modules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46742802/1555615).

You can use maven's `copy-dependencies` to make sure that all dependencies are copied under `target/lib` during `mvn package`.

### next step: jlink

Since `jlink` maven plugin is still in `alpha`, you can use command-line.

NOTES:

- `jlink` will create a self-contained bundle directory that contains

  - main app module
  - app dependencies
  - jdk required modules
  - app launcher (optional)
- `jlink` bundle targets **one platform at a time**. By **default** it is the **current platform.**
- `javafx` runtime modules are also **platform-specific**. But since they are **not part of the jdk** we need to **always provide the module-path** containing them.
- `javafx` runtime modules can be [downloaded from web](https://gluonhq.com/products/javafx/), or [from maven repo](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjfx) by using the corresponding target platform `classifier` (win/linux/mac).
- `jlink` can also create **cross-platform bundles**. Just include the target platform modules to the `--module-path` (e.g. from linux: download windows `jdk`/ `javafx` and add their `jmods` dirs to `module-path`).

#### jlink command

**Case 1:** **build and target** platforms are the **same**

NOTE: `/path-to/javafx-mods` needs to be provided to your `modulepath` unless you copy the required javafx deps under `lib/` using maven (copy-dependencies).

```sh
jlink --launcher run=jdk14Example/com.example.javafx.app.Main \
--module-path ./lib:javafx-jdk14-example-1.0.0.jar:/path-to/javafx-mods \
--add-modules=jdk14Example --output app-bundle
```

**Case 2:** **build and target** platforms are **differrent**

```sh
# Building from linux for windows
jlink --launcher run=jdk14Example/com.example.javafx.app.Main  \
--module-path ./lib:javafx-jdk14-example-1.0.0.jar:/path-to/jdk-win/jmods:/path-to/javafx-mods-win \
--add-modules=jdk14Example --output app-bundle
```

### Conclusion:

In both of the above cases you get a directory with a self-contained application which can run on a workstation with no `java`/`javafx` installed.

```sh
# if jlink targeted linux
app-bundle/bin/run

# if jlink targeted windows
app-bundle/bin/run.bat

# if jlink targeted mac
app-bundle/bin/run
```